# How to save a .dat file to a certain directory on my desktop

Tags: java, eclipse

I am writing Java code to generate .dat and .idx files, which I can do.
The files are saved to my workspace folder which I set up as a default when I started Eclipse.

Now I want to save these files and only these files I create to another directory on my server.
Is there code that can do this or do I have to change the settings in Eclipse to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a easy thing. Check below if this is what you want. Use

```
File file = new File("C:\\results\\results.txt");
```

C:\results\ is your outside directory.

Answer (score 2):

No you can definitely do it programmatically. When specifying the path use something like:

```
"/c/users/someperson/desktop/blah.dat"
```